# Combine built-in tags in templates with variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to combine the built-in tag: {% url %} with a dynamic url which I parse with {{ url_value }}
I tried doing: {% url 'urlname' url_value %}, but it didn't work
This is the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product', name='product_detail'),
```

{{url_value }} just represents the slug

Comment: Does "combine" mean "concatenate"? If so, {% url 'urlname' %}{{ url_value }} should work.

Comment: It's still doesn't work. I forgot to mention that the url receives a slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be like:

```
{% url product_detail slug=url_value %}
```